# Collections.sort with object key=0

Tags: sorting, collections, java-7

My Collections.sort() doesn't work when objects in my list have primaryKey=0 even if it's about comparing dates. Why is that!

```
private void sortListByDate(List<MyObject> listMyObject) {
    Collections.sort(listMyObject, new Comparator<MyObject>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(MyObject o1, MyObject o2) {
                return o2.getTariffDate().compareTo(o1.getTariffDate());

        }
     });
    }

example of input:  
list of 3 objects:  
    First Object: key:0 , tariffDate: 27/11/2018  
    Second Object: key:0 , tariffDate: 26/11/2018  
    Third Object: key:0 , tariffDate:28/11/2018

Output expected:  
    First Object: key:0 , tariffDate: 26/11/2018  
    Second Object: key:0 , tariffDate: 27/11/2018  
    Third Object: key:0 , tariffDate:28/11/2018
```

Have to mention, the keys are 0 because they are not created yet in database.

Comment: What's the return type of `o1.getTariffDate()`? Also what do you mean by "it doesn't work" ?

Comment: it's comparing Dates type Date, the list is the same as initial, but it works perfectly when key object is not 0.

Comment: "it works perfectly when key object is not 0". Did you mean `null` ?

Comment: No i meant not null but different from 0 like 2 , 555 , 25  ....

Comment: Please provide a clear example of what output you expect and the one you have. It's unclear what the "key object" is. You're comparing dates, while your "keys" are "2, 255, 25... "

Comment: it's an Object, having key as primary key, and other attributes like tariffDate. example of input:                                                                                               list of 3 object:
       First Object: key:0 , tariffDate: 27/11/2018
       Second Object: key:0 , tariffDate: 26/11/2018
       Third Object: key:0 , tariffDate:28/11/2018                                            Output expected:
         First Object: key:0 , tariffDate: 26/11/2018
         Second Object: key:0 , tariffDate: 27/11/2018    
         Third Object: key:0 , tariffDate:28/11/2018

Comment: What output are you getting now? Besides, what's the type of tariffDate?